# Undefined php function error

Tags: php

Hey guys so here is my code:

```
<?php
function editEntry($entry)
{
    echo $entry;
}

function deleteEntry($entry)
{
    echo $entry;
}

/*Edit on $_POST*/
if(isset($_POST["edit"]))
{
    $entry = $_POST["edit"];
    editEntry($entry);
}

/*Delete on $_POST*/
else if(isset($_POST["delete"]))
{
    $entry = $_POST["delete"];
    deleteEntry($entry);
}
?>
```

Although,on run I am getting this error:

```
Call to undefined function editEntry() in ... on line 18
```

What could be the problem??I really don't know why that would happen.What do you guys think?

Comment: Is this your real code? Doesn't seem like is.

Comment: Yes it is.I want just to echo some post values lulz

Comment: I don't think it is, see http://3v4l.org/9SNep

Comment: I don't think. The reason for this error is, that you don't have the function `editEntry` when you call it. In this code, you have

Comment: Found out what was the reason of the error,god damn forgot to reupload the code ,thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the code you posted and it does not return an error.

Comment: Strangely it does on my webserver.Would be poorly set-up apache causing it?

Comment: No. More likly some old version is cached. In this case i check always by `echo time();`

Comment: I don't think your web server would change a thing. Make sure the code is the same. Is it possible your function editEntry() as a typo in the original code?

Comment: I found out which was the reason,a very newby one.I didn't upload the code on the webserver>.<,now after I reuploaded it works just fine.Thanks for help!

Comment: No problem. Those types of mistakes happen to everyone. Cheers.